When will the transitioning context be nil in transitionDuration(using:)?
According to the documentation, one should return the duration for the transition in the transitionDuration(using:) method when implementing the UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol.
If we are returning different durations based on the transitioning context, how should we handle the case where the context is nil ? Or is it safe to assume the context will never be nil ? Thanks

I have no idea why this parameter is typed as an Optional, but that doesn't change the rules of life / style. Never use force-unwrapping in the application's code. If you need the context, unwrap it safely. If the context is nil, return some default duration.
